# Mosaico or CiviMail appending Sample Header/Footer Language to emails?

Tags: civimail, mosaico

I don't know what triggered this, but mosaico is appending

```
Sample Header for HTML formatted content.
```

at the top of each message and

```
Sample Footer for HTML formatted content
Unsubscribe 
Address Info
```

I know I can disable this on traditional CiviMail emails but how can i disable this with mosaico emails.

Latest Civi/WordPress

Edit: Disabling header and footer in admin *Headers, Footers, and Automated Messages* makes no difference.

Edit: I have Mosaico Message Templates & Pretty Workflow Messages installed but this was fine before and disabling both make no difference.

Edit 2: I rebuilt the template and email from scratch and the problem seems to have resolved itself. Very strange.

Its faint to see, but see message.

[image]

Comment: same situation, very strange

Comment: opened a ticket here: https://github.com/veda-consulting-company/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/issues/517

Answer (score 3):

Until this gets fixed, if you have a mailing where you are experiencing this issue and don't have time to rebuild your template and email from scratch, you can find your mailing in the `civicrm_mailing` table and set the `header_id` and `footer_id` fields to `NULL`.

Comment: This worked for me too!

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this as well. Fixed it by removing the text for the Mailing Header and Mailing Footer under Administer > CiviMail > Headers, Footers, and Automated Messages.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is fixed in https://github.com/veda-consulting-company/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/pull/536 so this should be fixed in 2.10.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the 2 entries in the table `civicrm_mailing_component` was my ugly but working solution

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had fixed it by unchecking default next to mailing header.  It no longer showed up in preview.  Also, it was null in the mailing tables, but when I went to send the message it errored with the missing domain.address, action.OptOutURL or action.UnsubscribeURL.  I ended up adding a foot id in the table to send it. This was for a message copied from before the upgrade.  It appears to do the right thing when I create a new message from a template.

Answer (score 0):

@Sean T. Walsh:
Administer > CiviMail > Headers, Footers, and Automated Messages
was a good hint, but deactivating didn't solve the issue for existing mails / templates.
My hack: Edit Header / Footer and delete or <!-- comment out --> the contents.